# What difference does it make to use the increment operator before the continue statement in a while loop? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, break, continue

I was trying to code along a tutorial on using the "continue" statement in a while loop. In the tutorial, the code was written as shown below and it worked fine.

```
            ...var x = 1;
            document.write("Entering loop");

            while (x < 20) {
                x++;
                if (x == 5) {
                    continue;
                }
                
                document.write(x + "<br />");
            }
            document.write("Exiting the loop");...
```

but I tried it differently and it resulted  to an infinite loop when I put the increment statement after the "if" block as shown below.

```
                ...
                var x = 1;
                document.write("Entering loop");
    
                while (x < 20) {
                    
                    if (x == 5) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    x++;
                    document.write(x + "<br />");
                }
                document.write("Exiting the loop");
               ...
```

I have tried to wrap my head around it but I have not been able to figure it out. Why is this so?

Comment: Once `x` equals 5 it will endlessly continue, and never adjust the x again

Comment: Yoou know `continue` breaks the current loop immediately, and starts the next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
                if (x == 5) {
                    continue;
                }
```

alone means that x will never change once it reaches 5. Putting x++ before that means that x will change.

With x++ after, the loop will `continue` every time, infinitely.